# ItemListener not registering

Tags: java, swing

Im trying to learn some Java basics with this this book "Java in easy Steps", but in this section called " Handling Item events" where we use ItemListener, ItemEvent, itemStateChanged(), among others, the book seems to be incorrect. I have written everything they have told me to write, checked and double checked, yet the code does not want to work. Here is the code:

(It's supposed to be a window with some clickable options which register in its text box)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

class States extends JFrame implements ItemListener {
    JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
    String[] styles = { "Deep Dish", "Gourmet Style", "Thin and Crispy" };
    JComboBox<String> box = new JComboBox<String>(styles);
    JRadioButton rad1 = new JRadioButton("White");
    JRadioButton rad2 = new JRadioButton("Red");
    ButtonGroup wines = new ButtonGroup();
    JCheckBox chk = new JCheckBox("Pepperoni");
    JTextArea txtArea = new JTextArea(5, 38);

    public States() {
        super("Swing Window");
        setSize(500, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(pnl);
        setVisible(true);
        wines.add(rad1);
        wines.add(rad2);
        pnl.add(rad1);
        pnl.add(rad2);
        pnl.add(txtArea);
        pnl.add(box);
        pnl.add(chk);
        rad1.addItemListener(this);
        rad2.addItemListener(this);
        chk.addItemListener(this);
        box.addItemListener(this);
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
        if (event.getItemSelectable() == rad1) {
            txtArea.setText("White wine selected");
        }
        if (event.getItemSelectable() == rad2) {
            txtArea.setText("Red wine selected");
        }
        if ((event.getItemSelectable() == chk) && (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)) {
            txtArea.append("\nPepperoni selected\n");
        }
        if ((event.getItemSelectable() == box) && (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)) {
            txtArea.append(event.getItem().toString() + "selected");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        States gui = new States();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Please help us help you: 1) first and foremost, tell us what's wrong with the code you've posted, how it's not working -- details **do** matter. 2) please strive to only post well-formatted code, not all left-justified code which is hard to read.

Comment: OK, I've formatted your code for you, so hopefully by making it easier to read, we'll attract more experts who will be willing to put in the effort to read and understand it, but you still need to tell us why and how it's not working.

Comment: Except the GUI appears blank at first because pack() should be called just before setVisible(true), and these two should be called after all the components have been added, everything seems to work fine here. So, once again, what do you expect, and what do you observe?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay. Here's the direct result from the Command Prompt when I try to compile the code:

Comment: .\ItemListener.java:17: error: invalid method declaration; return type required
public Action(){
       ^
Statess.java:5: error: interface expected here
class Statess extends JFrame implements ItemListener{
                                        ^

Comment: Why do you have a file named ItemListener.java? ItemListener is an interface of the JDK. You must not create it yourself. Your class is named States. so it must be in a file named States.java, not Statess.java. Post all the relevant error messages in your question. Not in comments.

Comment: "Error invalid method declaration, return type required Public Action"

Comment: Sorry im trying to figure out this thing

Comment: I dont know why that is the case, i have not created any file nade ItemListener.java

Comment: The other mistake is: Statess.java:33: error: incompatible types: Statess cannot be converted to ItemListener
rad1.addItemListener( this );

Comment: Remove ALL the .java files except the one containing the code you posted. Make sure the only file remaining is named States.java, NOT Statess.java. Then it will compile. You keep posting error messages in comments instead of the question itself, and regarding code that is not part of the class you're asking about.

Comment: You were right, I did have a .java file named ItemListener... Dont know why, but the problem has been solved. Thanks so much

Comment: *"I did have a .java file named ItemListener... Dont know why"* My guess would be because you are selecting the suggestions of an IDE. Suggestions you have not made any effort to understand.

Comment: Sorry for disappointing you Andrew Thompson sensei, I have brought dishonor to your healthy brain and good name. For this I will pay the ultimate price, goodbye...

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set your `JFrame` to be visible. Add following code in your `main` method. Also delete `setVisible(true);` in your contructor method `States()` since at that time the `JFrame` hasn't added all its components.

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            States gui = new States();
            gui.pack();
            gui.setVisible(true);

        }

    });
```

Comment: thanks for your anwser, the code works either way. The problem seemed to be a file i had named ItemListener.java that was messing me up. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @Melvinml This code actually doesn't work since it will show you a blank screen. Setting the frame to be visible in it's own constructor is not the right way to use it.

Comment: I did not remove the original setVisible(true)

Comment: Also, sometimes It is blank until you maximize the window, it has happened to me before

Comment: @Melvinml Yes, even so, It runs everything on main thread and it even paused a while to show all the components. which I don't think is a good practice.

Comment: Other than that I cant help you, im just a beginner... I just do what the book tells me. Thanks for your input anyways

Comment: @Melvinml no.. it's not helping me... it's helping yourself, you should do what I added in my updated answer, which is the right way to do Swing GUI in Java.

Comment: Hey man, I just tried it and it worked. In fact, it worked equally to the first one you gave me. They are a bit different from my original code which works too. I dont know why, I dont know how, but thats the way it seems to be. Thanks for teaching me some new code,though